# Efficient Market Hypothesis paradox?

Tags: emh

Here's an apparent paradox that puzzles me.
EMH states that asset prices reflect all information available. Investors are assumed to be rational. We can note:

$E(p_{t+1}|\Phi_{t}) = (1+E(r_{t+1}|\Phi_{t}))*p_{t}$

Where E is the expected value operator. $p_{t}$ the price at time t, $r_{t+1}$ the expected one-period return, $\Phi_{t}$ is a general symbol for whatever set of information is assumed to be "fully reflected" in the price at t.

My question is what happens at time $t+1$ and after. I see 3 cases:

**Case 1:** no new piece of information susceptible to move the price is released. In that case you would expect the price to remain unchanged since all information is already priced in and there is no incentive for a rational economic agent to invest.

**Case 2:** a new piece of information is released at some point in the future. If you don't what to make any assumption on that future piece of information, you have to assume that pieces of information that drive the price up are as probable as pieces of information that drive the price down. In that case the expected return is 0 by construction and price should remain unchanged. So again no incentive for the agent to invest.

**Case 3:** you assume the piece of information is likely to drive the price in one particular direction, either up or down. By doing so you also assume a pattern in the future returns which is contrary to what the EMH states.

How can one resolve that apparent paradox?

Comment: "In that case the expected return is 0 by construction". No, the EMH allows for a positive return in the absence of information due to the time value of money and a risk premium for holding stocks. This return is small, a few basis points per day, a few percent a year. But you are right that with EMH there is no incentive for an investor without special information to act.

Comment: You may be ineterested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grossman-Stiglitz_Paradox

Comment: Thanks @nbbo2 super useful!

Comment: While I disagree with cases 2 and 3, you point to the right problem: the sheer amount of trading is indeed puzzling and it's not quite clear why there is soo much trading in financial markets to translate information into prices.